# Is it possible and interesting to define a complex measure (of curves) based on integrating a meromorphic/holomorphic function?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

If we have $f$ a complex function, then we can define $\mu$ like this:

given a curve $C$, $\mu(C)= \int_{C} f dz$

I'm suspecting strongly that, unless $f$ is zero a.e or something similar, my measure will have problems with the $\sigma$-additivity, as maybe I'll have to do $\infty + \infty$.

Maybe we can ask only for finite additivity...

What I want is to use the Residue Theorem and/or the Argument Principle, and see if I can prove some interesting facts for my measure.

Does anywone know is this has been discussed? I've been thinking for some days, and searching, but I didn't find anything.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain more precisely what you mean?  How exactly is this measure supposed to be "based on" integrating a holomorphic function?  What set is this measure supposed to be defined on?

Comment: I edited the description of the question!